# Creating Calculator with Class - C#, However unable to solve error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a Calculator with a Class. However using references from the internet particularly from this website (https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/c/7548/simple-calculator-using-class-c.html)

It did not mention to declare "Information" or whatsoever.

When I typed in the code, the error list return with Information does not exist in current context.

Is there a way to modify the code below? Thank you so much.

```
public partial class Form4 : Form
    {


        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void RadioButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

            //call a constructor method and return to cal as an instance of a class
            calculate cal = new calculate();

            //declaring the string variable represent as a textbox
            string txtnum1 = TextBox1.Text;
            string txtnum2 = TextBox2.Text;
            //declaring the double variable
            double dbl_val1 = default(double);
            double dbl_val2 = default(double);



            if (**Information**.IsNumeric(txtnum1) && **Information**.IsNumeric(txtnum2)) //check if the textbox has a numeric value
            {
                //convert the string to double
                dbl_val1 = double.Parse(txtnum1);
                dbl_val2 = double.Parse(txtnum2);

                //get the value of the converted variable
                //to pass it into the variable in the class
                cal.num1 = dbl_val1;
                cal.num2 = dbl_val2;

                //the condition is, if the radiobutton is clicked,
                //the operation of MDAS executes.
                if (Radio_Multiplication.Checked)
                {
                    //result:
                    cal.multiply(); //call a subname in a class for multiplying
                }

                else if (Radio_Addition.Checked)
                {
                    //result:
                    cal.add(); //call a subname in a class for adding
                }
                else if (Radio_Subtraction.Checked)
                {
                    //result:
                    cal.subtract(); //call a subname in a class for subtracting
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //the result is:
                //if the textbox is empty or has a string value
                TextBox3.Text = "Enter a number";
                return;
            }
            //put the result of the MDAS to a textbox.
            TextBox3.Text = cal.total.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is a "Download Code" button, you should download the code, hit F12 in visual stuido with your text cursor on the property and find out where it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick look at the link and they don't appear to have declared Information anywhere nor have they indicated that they've overridden anything so...I don't know.

That line, however, is just validating that the information entered into the two text boxes are actually numbers and not anything else that can't be calculated.

There are lots of methods you could use to check those numbers. Options would include, but are not limited to:

```
if(Int32.TryParse(txtNum1, out int temp1) && Int32.TryParse(txtNum2, out int temp2))
{
  do stuff;
}
```

or

```
if(txtNum1.All(char.IsDigit) && txtNum2.All(char.IsDigit))
{
  do stuff;
}
```

There are other options, but those two might be worth looking into.

Comment: Your first option is not going to be very useful, since the second `TryParse` is going to override the result of the first `TryParse`. You're going to need a second temporary variable.

Comment: As a point of interest, in C#7 you don't even need a `temp` variable. You can instead write the parse as `Int32.TryParse(txtNum1, out int temp1)` and `temp1` will be accessible within the `if` block.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Oops, you're right! Shame on me. I shall update my answer so as I don't lead others astray.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the sample project, I had a look at what `Information` refers to. Turns out, it's [a class from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information(v=vs.110).aspx), presumably for exposing certain aspects of the VB core library to all .NET languages. You can use it in your program by adding a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` to your project and adding:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
```

to the top of your code file.

(Personally, I can't imagine that this approach is terribly efficient. It's supposed to take an `object` and determine if it can be evaluated as a number, and I have no idea what approaches it uses to make that deduction based on any random `object`. You would probably be better off using one of the alternatives that Benny O'Neill suggests.)

Comment: @Izzuan Don't forget to mark one of the given answers as the solution.